# How to customize the method templates in Visual Studios

Tags: visual-studio, ide-customization

Is there a way to customize/edit the default template of the event handling methods in Visual Studios 2008/2010 such that upon creation, the event handler already has a try/catch block in it?

the default behavior is

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

I'd like to be able to set the development environment to do

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ///TODO: Add logic here
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }
```

I've already edited the templates located in the ItemTemplates folder so that they meet the coding standard where I work, but I'd also like to edit the method templates if possible.  I've searched the 'Net for the better part of a week and found nothing.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

![Snippet Manager[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmQK7.jpg)

Have you considered Editing Event method stub in the Code Snippet manager or adding a new snippet?

Comment: I had not even looked there. (truthfully, I didn't even know that functionality existed.) I'll check out the Snippet manager, and let you know if that works.

Comment: So, I looked in to the Snippet Manager.  While it did provide some functionality and allowed me to fix some other issues; I was unable to force VS2010 to use the newly modified snippets.

Thanks though.